# Let $R$ and $S$ be two commutative rings with unity and $f : R → S$ be a ring homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ and $S$ be two commutative rings with unity and $f : R → S$ be a ring homomorphism.

Then which of the following statement(s) is/are true ?

$a.$ Image of an ideal of R is always an ideal in S.

$b$. Image of an ideal of R is an ideal of S if f is injective.

$c$. Image of an ideal of R is an ideal of S if f is surjective.

$d.$ Image of an ideal of R is an ideal of S if S is a field.

if  i take  $R = S  = Z_2$ then  option b ),  c)  and d)  are corrects...

im  confused  about  option 1)..

Any  Hints/solution....

Thanks in advance

Comment: Four questions for the price of one! Don't forget, $R$ is always an ideal of $R$.

Comment: ... and maybe consider $f:\Bbb Q\hookrightarrow\Bbb R$.